# Почему результат выражения null + {0:1}[0] + [,[1],][1][0] равен 2?

Tags: javascript, null, type-error, nan

Мои попытки понять:

```js
console.log(null + {0:1}[0] + [,[1],][1][0]); // 2
console.log(null + {0:1}[0] + [,[2],][1][0]); // 3
console.log(null + {0:1}[0] + [,['2'],][1][0]); // 12


console.log(null + {0:1}[1] + [,[1],][1][0]); // NaN
console.log(null + {0:1}[0] + [,[1],][1][1]); // NaN

console.log(null + {0:1}[0] + [,[1],][2][0]); // TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Comment: ой, может вам лучше спецификацию почитать? Ведь такие непонятные конструкции никто никогда не будет писать в коде, а базовые преобразования написаны в спеке. А то вы сейчас в такие дебри забретаете, а нужно с простого. Например, почему `[] + {} === "[object Object]"`, а `{} + [] === 0`

Comment: *Почему результат выражения null + {0:1}[0] + [,[1],][1][0] равен 2?* - потому что `null + 1 = 1` и `[,[1],][1][0] = 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давай разберем это выражение: `null + {0:1}[0] + [,[1],][1][0]`
`null` - можно отбросить так как это "ничего", оно приводится к 0.

`{0:1}` - это объект, у которого по ключу 0 значение 1.

`[0]` - получение значения по нулевому ключу от объекта, таким образом:

`{0:1}[0]` - получить значение объекта {0:1} по ключу 0. Это значение равно 1.

Идем дальше, разберем `[,[1],][1][0]`.

`[,[1],]` - это массив, нулевое значение перед запятой будет пустым (`<1 empty item>`),
первое значение равно `[1]` и является вложенным массивом, нулевое значение которого равно 1. Т.е. весь этот массив можно представить так - `[ <1 empty item>, [ 1 ] ]`
Далее `[1][0]` - взять первое значение исходного массива и взять нулевое значение вложенного массива т.е. выражение `[,[1],][1][0]` будет равно `[1][0]`, где `[1]` - вложенный массив, нулевое значение которого равно 1.

Таким образом значение `[,[1],][1][0] = 1`.
Итого получаем `null + {0:1}[0] + [,[1],][1][0] = 1 + 1 = 2`

Comment: `[undefined, [1], undefined]` — не совсем так (можете проверить, что выдаёт `[,[1],]` в консоли). Последняя запятая игнорируется, так что третьего элемента вообще не будет. А на месте первого будет дырка (hole), там не будет даже `undefined`. Это отличие важно, так как при переборах элементов массива часто бывает так, что `undefined` вызывает срабатывание итерации, а дырка не вызывает. Подробнее см. https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_arrays.html#array-holes

Comment: Да, вы правы, сейчас проверил действительно будет [ <1 empty item>, [ 1 ] ]. Исправил ответ

Answer (score 2):

`null + {0:1}[0] + [,[1],][1][0]`

---

В арифметических операциях `null` преобразуется в `0`

```js
console.log( null + 5 ); // 5
console.log( 5 + null ); // 5
console.log( 5 * null ); // 0
```

---

`{0: 1}[0]` — Из объекта `{0: 1}` достается значение свойства `"0"`, т.е. `1`.

```js
console.log( {0: 1}[0] ); // 1

let obj = {0: 1};
console.log( obj[0] ); // 1, то же самое.

obj = {a: 1};
console.log( obj['a'] ); // тоже 1. Пусть 0 не запутывает...

console.log( {a: 1}['a'] );
```

---

`[,[1],][1][0]` выполняется слева направо.

`[,[1],]` — создается массив из двух ячеек, `[empty, [1]]` (в массиваx и объектах последняя запятая игнорируется)

```js
let arr = [,[1],];

console.log( arr.length ); // 2
console.log( arr[0] ); // undefined
console.log( arr[1] ); // [1] ◄*

console.log( [,[1],][1] ); // [1] ◄*
```

А если `[,[1],][1]` дает массив `[1]`, получается `( [,[1],][1] )[0]` → `[1][0]`

Где `[1]` — массив с одним элементом `1`, который находится под индексом `0`. Этот элемент и получается при выполнении:

```js
console.log( [1][0] ); // 1

let arr = [1];
console.log( arr[0] ) // 1 (то же самое).

///
console.log( [5, 7, 9][0] ); // 5
console.log( [5, 7, 9][1] ); // 7
console.log( [5, 7, 9][2] ); // 9
```

---

```
null + {0:1}[0] + [,[1],][1][0]
 ↓        ↓          ↓
 0   +    1     +    1          = 2
```

---

Ну и, список ваших попыток из вопроса:

```
null + {0:1}[0] + [,[2],][1][0]); // 3
  0  +    1     +    2

null + {0:1}[0] + [,['2'],][1][0]); // 12
  0  +    1     +    '2'
// это конкатенация со строкой, а не суммирование, получается строка "12"

null + {0:1}[1] + [,[1],][1][0]); // NaN
  0  + undefined+    1   // у объекта {0:1} нет свойства 1
                         // любая арифметика с undefined дает NaN

null + {0:1}[0] + [,[1],][1][1]); // NaN
  0  +    1     + ( [1]    )[1]   // у массива [1] нет индекса 1, только нулевой 
  0  +    1     +  undefined

null + {0:1}[0] + [,[1],][2][0]); // TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
  0  +    1     + (undefined)[0]  // У массива [,[1],] нет [2]-го элемента. undefined
```

Comment: В массиве будет не три, а два элемента. недавно ввели trailing comma в массивах

Comment: Ой вру, в массивах они кажется всегда были

Comment: @AlexeyTen Спасибо, забылЪ )